# Basic Modal Logic question #1

Tags: modal-logic

Its about two weeks I have started Cresswell's "A New Introduction To modal Logic".
Now I've got a few questions on the text and I would deeply thank you if you help me clarify on them.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The first among them will be as follows:
To prove $K$-Validity of the system $K$ (i.e. that every theorem of the system $K$ is $K$-Valid; or in other words, is valid in every frame $(W,R)$ ), the book is using induction on the set of theorems. So:
(a) It first tries to prove it for all valid formulas of Propositional Calculus (i.e. Tautologies of PC), plus the axiom $K$, are $K$-Valid; And
(b) it shows that the Transformation rules of the system $K$, preserve $K$-validity.

---

Now in part (a), to prove that every tautology of PC is $K$-Valid, the author argues in the following way:

> In any model, a PC wff is evaluated in any world without reference to
>   any other world. **Therefore, since a valid wff has the value $1$ for
>   every value-assignment to the variables, it has the value $1$ in every
>   world in every model, i.e. it is valid on every frame**.

But the author has defined validity of a formula in world, recursively, such that its base is such that if $V$ is a Value-assignmet, then "For any atomic formula $a$ , and any world $w$ ,either $V(a,w)=1$ or $V(a,w)=0$"
[And then he continues to define valuation of other formulas, recursively; that we don't care here]
So,the way the book shows is that: Value-assignmet are functions of form  $V: PROP\times W \longrightarrow  \{0,1\}$   that as we saw, are not dependent to any kind of valuation of propositions in PC.

***So why the author argues as above, while there is no connection between valuations of formulas in PC and valuations of them (in worlds) in the system $K$?***

Answer (score 1):

The recursive definition of valuation of other formulas is the key. In particular, the valuation of formulas constructed using non-modal connectives only uses the valuation of the component formulas in the current world.

More precisely, for every modal valuation $V$ and every world $w$, you can define a PC-valuation $V_w$ by $V_w(a)=V(a,w)$, and then you can show by induction on the complexity of $\phi$ that if $\phi$ is a PC-formula, then $V(\phi,w)=V_w(\phi)$ (or, $w\models_V\phi\iff\models_{V_w}\phi$, or whatever notation Hughes and Cresswell use for valuation of compound formulas). If $\phi$ is a PC-valid, then $V_w(\phi)=1$, thus $V(\phi,w)=1$. Since $V$ and $w$ were arbitrary, $\phi$ is $K$-valid.

Comment: What worlds are we talking about when we are defining valuation of PC formulas based on their valuation on arbitrary worlds.

Comment: The quote in your question starts with “in any model”. We are talking about worlds of that model, of course.

Comment: I mean what is the meaning of a world in the context of PC? Anyway, based on what you assert, we must have that: A PC-valid formula is the one that is true in every existing world.And then it is true in every world which is in relation to the a special world. So it is necessary in every world. right? It is coherent with the Semantical interpretation of the rule of necessitation , i think!

Comment: There are no worlds in the context of PC. There are just valuations.

Comment: So, what about the argumentation i just did? Am i right on it? And do you agree  that in a level of some meta-language for PC, we are using the concept of worlds? I mean, can we count the modal systems (here K) as a meta language for PC? Thanks anyway

Comment: I don’t understand much what you are trying to say. A “world” is just a fancy word for an element of the given model, so I don’t know what you mean by “existing” or “special”. PC has a more restricted language than K, but for formulas that are in its language, its usual semantics behaves the same as the K semantics in a single world. K is certainly not a metalanguage for PC, they are both object languages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think the unclarity is more a matter of philosophy than math.
You said we can define the valuation of formulas in PC by combining it with the world conception.And 
Then it results that a formula in PC is valid iff it is valid in every world.
Now the ambiguity arises here for me: When i am in the context of PC, i understand truth of an atomic proposition independent from 
anything else[and then other formulas, recursively on them, by their definition of truth]. No tool in mathematical logic is to check the truth of an atomic proposition;
It's a matter of philosophy and theories of truth; and for example if we accept the Correspondence approach to truth, it's somehow a matter of corresponding to the 
real world(take intuitively the "world" as what we are living in- or the state of affairs). 
Now the question is that when we define the truth of PC formulas by the modal concept 'world'(Or as you said, a member of the arbitrarily chosen set W in a model) 
and we say that for example v(a,w)=1 and v(a,w')=0 for an atomic formula a , what is the meaning of such assertions? What is the meaning of truth in a world here? I don't understand it neither mathematically nor non-mathematically!

Tell me if i am still unclear with the question.